# Selenium - Get all cells under column header

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to get all `td` (cells) under a specific `th` (header)

**HTML:**

```
<table width="800">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><b>User ID</b></th>
            <th><b>Workforce ID</b></th>
            <th><b>Given Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Surname</b></th>
            <th><b>Division</b></th>
            <th><b>Hire Date</b></th>
            <th><b>Department</b></th>
            <th><b>emplType</b></th>
            <th><b>Associations</b></th>
            <th><b>SAP Roles</b></th>
            <th><b>Community</b></th>
            <th><b>Active</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="active"><a href="?username=utest001">utest001</a></td>
            <td class="active">00700001</td>
            <td class="active">User</td>
            <td class="active">Test001</td>
            <td class="active">Coles</td>
            <td class="active">2015-10-27</td>
            <td class="active">CHFITVB</td>
            <td class="active">S</td>
            <td class="active">IAM</td>
            <td class="active"></td>
            <td class="active">Workforce</td>
            <td class="active">Y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="disabled"><a href="?username=utest002">utest002</a></td>
            <td class="disabled">00700002</td>
            <td class="disabled">Vasia</td>
            <td class="disabled">Smith</td>
            <td class="disabled">Coles</td>
            <td class="disabled">2015-11-16</td>
            <td class="disabled">C0584SV</td>
            <td class="disabled">W</td>
            <td class="disabled"></td>
            <td class="disabled"></td>
            <td class="disabled">Workforce</td>
            <td class="disabled">N</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Method:**

```
public List<WebElement> getCellsUnderHeader(WebElement table, String headerName) {
    List<WebElement> thList = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("th > b"));
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    thList.stream().forEach(th -> headers.add(th.getText()));
    int index = headers.indexOf(headerName);
    List<WebElement> trList = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> tdList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> columnCells = new ArrayList<>();
    WebElement cell = null;
    for (WebElement tr : trList) {
        tdList = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        cell = tdList.get(index); // Getting out of bounds here
        columnCells.add(cell);
    }
    return columnCells;
}
```

**Actual Result:**

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

**Expected Result:**

Return a `List<WebElement>` containing 2 `td` (with `a` tag) under header `User ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trList` contains the `<tr>` with the headers, which doesn't have `<td>` tags so in the first `for` iteration `tdList` is empty and `tdList.get(index)` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can iterate by index instead

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < trList.size() ; i++) {
    tdList = trList.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    cell = tdList.get(index);
    columnCells.add(cell);
}
```

Or ship first item

```
for (WebElement tr : trList.subList(1, trList.size())) {
    tdList = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    cell = tdList.get(index);
    columnCells.add(cell);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the `subList()` was elegant. Changed to lambdas too.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :**

> For the first **tr** iteration there was no **td** available, which in
>   result causing the exception

**Use Following :**

```
public List<WebElement> getCellsUnderHeader(WebElement table, String headerName) {
        List<WebElement> thList = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("th > b"));
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        thList.stream().forEach(th -> headers.add(th.getText()));
        int index = headers.indexOf(headerName);
        System.out.println("Index : "+index);
        List<WebElement> trList = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        List<WebElement> tdList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<WebElement> columnCells = new ArrayList<>();
        WebElement cell = null;
        for (WebElement tr : trList) {
            tdList = tr.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            if (tdList.size()>0){
                cell = tdList.get(index); // Getting out of bounds here
                columnCells.add(cell);
            }
        }
        return columnCells;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was _almost_ there.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> userIDs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td/a"))
            .stream()
            .map(elem -> elem.getText())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would like a reusable method that can take any header (`User ID` was an example) and return the cells under it.